# constructor understanding issue

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to understand what is a constructor and could you tell me why I am still able to run the program without error?

As you can see I am not doing it correctly but it still works!! why??
and when I tried to put LL=(object name ) after my class DELL it is not working? but when I retrieved the LL it works why??? If I am not clear do not hesitate to tell me
and I am sorry in advance for this mess

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class DELL{
public:
    DELL(){
        cout <<" bla bl bla\n";
    }
    void setname(string x){
        name = x;
}

        string getname()
        {
            return name;}
private:
string name;


};

int main(){

    DELL (); // Variant 1
    DELL LL(); // Variant 2
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `main` functions? And when you say "I am not doing it correctly", what is "it" and how are you not doing it correctly?

Comment: `DELL LL ();` is a function declaration.

Comment: `DELL ();` makes an anominous object of class `DELL`.

Comment: ok so i must have miss understand something i tought LL was an object

Comment: anonymous object? well i learnt something thank you for your reply

Comment: but i a m still confuse but thank you do not waste your time with me i am going to seek on google regarding your answer have a nice day by the way i was saying i am not doing correctly because iam following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b7odUc7lg0 regarding the constructor and the result is different from me lol this is why i am saying i am not doing correctly

Comment: Thank you g-v also for this knowledge!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's enhance your DELL class to add destructor to it. This will help us better understand the lifecycle of your object. Here is the code:

```
class DELL {
public:
    DELL() {
        std::cout << "DELL constructor called\n";
    }
    ~DELL() {
        std::cout << "DELL destructor called\n";
    }
};
```

Here are 3 possible ways you can play with this:

`DELL();` - This does construct a temporary object of type DELL(). It is deleted immediately after this, and since it is not used, optimized compilers might simply drop this line altogether. However, if you disable optimization and compile/link/run your code, you should see a constructor call, immediately followed by destructor call. Example code below will produce constructor, destructor, checkpoint printouts in this order.

```
DELL();
std::cout << "Checkpoint.\n";
```

`DELL LL;` this creates an object of type DELL. This object will live until the end of the scope where it will be declared. If you put this into your main, and than output something after this, like following

```
{
DELL LL;
std::cout << "Checkpoint.\n";
}
```

You will see constructor call, "Checkpoint" and than destructor call as your output (again, provided no optimization is taking place).

`DELL LL();` - this creates no objects. Instead, it declares a function named LL, which takes no arguments and return object of type DELL. When you run this code, you will see no output from constructor nor destructor, because no object was created.

Answer (score 0):

You've run afoul of a quirk of C++ grammar known as the Vexing Parse. In short:

```
DELL LL();
```

declares a function named `LL` which has no parameters and returns a `DELL` object. Compare the syntax of `DELL LL();` and `int main();`.

This code:

```
DELL();
```

creates a temporary object of type `DELL` and initialises it with the default constructor.

This code:

```
DELL LL;
```

creates an object named `LL`, of type `DELL`, and default-initialises it. For a class, that means calling the default constructor.

Starting with C++11, you can use curly braces instead of parentheses for initialisation, which avoids the vexing parse:

```
DELL LL{};
```

This creates an object `LL`, of type `DELL`, and value-initialises it. For a class, that again means calling the default constructor.

Comment: Maybe change "Vexing Parse" to link to this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse ?

Comment: @borisbn Thing is, this is not the Most Vexing Parse; that would be `T t(T());`. This is just the Vexing parse, `T t();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys all of you for this knowledge I hope one day i ll help you too!!

Comment: @Juststarted26092015 BTW, you might be interested in the [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) maintained here on SO.

Comment: Thanks really apreciate for this!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it 'wrong'. You are simply not doing it 'right'.

You declare a class called `DELL`, and it has only one constructor that requires no additional parameters.

```
public:
    DELL(){
        cout <<" bla bl bla\n";
    }
```

Now, in your `main()` you call that constructor but you don't create an object of `DELL` class;

Proper way to create an object of DELL would be:

```
DELL LL;
 //and then you could maybe do
LL.setname("name of object");
cout<<LL.getname();
```

When you would run this program the output would be:

```
 bla bla bla
name of object
```

Also, you could create a pointer to object of DELL by doing>

```
int main(){

    DELL *ll;
    ll = new DELL();

    ll->setname("name of object");
    cout<<ll->getname();

    return 0;
}
```

And the output would be the same as the one above.

Comment: By the way I know that you do not use a constructor for this kind of situation but on the other hand i thought i constructor from my research was a  kind special function  which would give the same things as your second example. but it was not just another way to write faster the code instead to use--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- DELL LL;
LL.setname("name of object");
cout<<LL.getname(); but i guess i was wrong and miss understood this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b7odUc7lg0 but thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you are saying... What I think you want is to set `name` in a constructor, and you can do that, but then you need a constructor with a `string` parameter... DELL(string str) {
        name = str;
    }

Comment: i was trying to do the same things as in this video     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b7odUc7lg0..... yes that is the  part 2 in the videos the guy show another example using ........................class buckysclass{
public:
 buckysclass(string z){
    setname(z);